# Transfer of Electrical Charges

Tags: electrostatics, charge, classical-electrodynamics

I'm having a lot of trouble understanding how charges transfer exactly. Suppose I have 3 particles $a,b,c$, $a$ is negatively charged, $b$ is positively charged and $c$ is neutral. We let the charges of $a,b$ be $\vert a \vert > \vert b \vert$. If say $a$ were to touch $c$ the neutrally charged particle and then $c$ were to touch $b$, what happens here?

$a$ and $b$ attract so I am assuming that $c$ picks up charge and will *also* attract $b$. But how much charge is transfer? Is it $\frac{a}{2}$ and would be something to be memorized? I'm curious why as well.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Suppose I have 3 particles a,b,c, a is negatively charged, b is positively charged and c is neutral. We let the charges of a,b be |a|>|b|. If say a were to touch c the neutrally charged particle and then c were to touch b, what happens here?

Elementary particles can't transfer charges by touching.

Let's consider composite particles (like atoms) that can transfer charges, and atom $a$ having greater negative charge than atom $b$ has positive. This is caused by atom $a$ having $n$ more electrons than protons, and atom $b$ having $m$ less electrons than protons, where $n>m$. If the pull from the nucleus of atom $b$ is strong enough, some electrons from atom $a$ will be attracted to atom $b$ strongly enough that they either leave atom $a$ completely, or they create a chemical bond with atom $b$ that will hold together by $a$'s electrons being attracted by $b$'s nucleus, and $b$'s electrons attracted by $a$'s nucleus.

In case of three atoms, $a$ might transfer some electrons to $c$, which then might transfer some to $b$.

In case of macroscopic objects, the charge is caused by charge carriers, such as free electrons (usually), ions (like in [electrolytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrolyte) or [plasma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_(physics))) or [holes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_hole) (like in [semiconductors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiconductor)).

For example, let's have two pieces of metal $a$ and $b$, $a$ with abundance of free electrons on the surface giving it negative charge, and $b$ with lack of free electrons on the surface giving it positive charge. When $a$ and $b$ are brought into physical contact, some free electrons from $a$'s surface move to $b$'s surface to equalize the [electric potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential) of both $a$ and $b$.

> But how much charge is transfer?

For simplicity, let's consider two spherical conductors $a$ and $b$. $a$ has charge $-Q_a$ and $b$ charge $Q_b$, where $Q_a>Q_b$. It can be shown that the electric potential of $a$ is $V_a=k\frac{-Q_a}{r_a}$ and the electric potential of $b$ is $V_b=k\frac{Q_b}{r_b}$, where $r_a$ is the radius of $a$, $r_b$ is the radius of $b$ and $k$ is [Coulomb's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb%27s_constant). If we denote the charge moved from $a$ to $b$ by $Q_\Delta$, we get

$$k\frac{-Q_a-Q_\Delta}{r_a}=k\frac{Q_b+Q_\Delta}{r_b}$$

because the new potentials must be equal. By solving for $Q_\Delta$, we get

$$Q_\Delta = -\frac{Q_ar_b + Q_br_a}{r_a + r_b}$$

which is the charge that will move from $a$ to $b$.

Comment: I'm looking up a homework solution and it starts out saying that the charge is split equally between $a$ and $c$ when they touch. Is this conceptual incorrect? here is a link [link]https://www.slader.com/textbook/9781118230718-fundamentals-of-physics-10th-edition/625/problems/8/[/link]

Comment: In the link, they're taking about spheres. Look at the equation I wrote for $Q_\Delta$: If you substitute $r_a = r_b$ and $Q_b = 0$, you'll get $Q_\Delta = -\frac{Q_a}2$, so for an uncharged $b$, $a$ gives away half of its charge, so their solution is correct.

Comment: (Btw, your link is broken and the correct link is here: https://www.slader.com/textbook/9781118230718-fundamentals-of-physics-10th-edition/625/problems/8/) 

Comment: @dls Also, I'm pinging you now because I didn't realize before that I had to ping you for you to be notified of my comments, so just to make sure you'll notice them.